# Changing hostname on startup

Tags: boot

can somebody write (or find) me a script that changes host name to actual first names and last names every start up ? the only ones ive found are ones that change the host name to fnds2ijf3, is there one that can run through a text file of random first and last names like ZachSmith ? please please let me know.

Comment: This question is too broad - please edit it and tell us what exactly your problem is. Do you need help how to run a script on boot? Or help with picking random lines from text files? See [How to ask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: dhcp servers can be configured to send a client's hostname.  and a dhcp client can be configured to set their hostname to whatever the dhcp server gives them.  I've never bothered to do this (so can't give an actual detailed answer), but it should be used in conjunction with a static IP allocation based on MAC address. And it would be a good idea to make sure that both forward and reverse (.in-addr.arpa) DNS entries match the hostname too.

Comment: OTOH, since it's a static allocation it's easier and better to just set /etc/hostname on the client and forget about it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.